# Why won't my python code add in my += if's?

Tags: python, algorithm, operators, addition

I am VERY new to coding. I seem to be stuck on the if/elif/else and the += operator. When I run my code it works partly. I don't get any errors, but it will not add in the Island and Heater in my code if both or one is "Y".

I made this up myself based off the practice that I had trouble with. I mimiced the solution to the practice problem but I am not getting the same results. Can someone please help me to see what I am doing wrong?

```
Size = int(input("What size camper do you want? Size in feet. \n"))
Island = input("Do you want and Island? y or n \n")
Heater = input("Do you want tankless water heater? y or n \n")

price = 0

if Size <= 30:
  price += 50000
elif Size <= 40:
  price += 60000
else:
  price += 80000

if Island == "Y or y":
  if Size <=30:
    price += 500
  else:
    price += 800

if Heater == "Y or y":
  if Size <=30:
    price += 1000
  else:
    price += 1500

print(f"Your total for a new camper will be ${price}!")
```

I tried changing the indents and I originally did not have the else options for the heater and the island.

Comment: `Island == "Y or y":` does not do what you think.

Comment: As a side note, its best to post fully contained examples when possible. Instead of us guessing about input, you could hard code values for `Size` and etc...

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `if Island == "Y or y":` checks whether the input is literally the string `"Y or y"`. Use `if Island.lower() == "y":` instead. Another option is `if Island in ("Y", "y"):`.

Comment: Thank you for that help. I haven't learned about that stuff yet, but it did fix the issue I was having. Fingers crossed I can figure this stuff out.